# Remove all items that match a condition in all documents in mongodb c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to remove all elements from a nested array that match a condition, my document looks like:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5658a636742a2f0bd8bfe3f1"),
"Name" : "Ade",
"Groups" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("565a4d79742a2f14f8d42239"),
        "Name" : "GrupoA",
        "Members" : [ 
            "F", 
            "B"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("565a4df2742a2f14f8d4223a"),
        "Name" : "GrupoB",
        "Members" : [ 
            "A", 
            "B", 
            "C"
        ]
    }
]}
```

and the code i'm using is:

```
var filter = Builders<ApplicationUser>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Groups, y => y.Members.Contains("B"));
var updateDefinition =  Builders<ApplicationUser>.Update.Pull("Groups.$.Members", "B");
collection.UpdateManyAsync(filter, updateDefinition);
```

but when I execute it, It only removes the "B" from "GrupoA", and I want to remove all "B" that are found in the array.

Comment: hi, were you able to solve this problem?